# combining information that meet criteria in one excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have to combine data that meet certain criteria. the background is: I have a list with parts for a car that has different model series (in this example X,Y,Z). One partnumber can appear multiple times in the list with different model series. I have to know which part is used in which model series.

for example my existing excel table looks like this:

```
partnumber    Model series
100           X
100           Y
100           X
100           Z
200           Z
200           Y
300           X
400           Y
400           Z
```

afterwards it should look like this:

```
partnumber    Model series    usage 
100           X               X,Y,Z
100           Y               X,Y,Z
100           X               X,Y,Z
100           Z               X,Y,Z
200           Z               Y,Z
200           Y               Y,Z
300           X               X
400           Y               X,Y
400           X               X,Y
400           Y               X,Y
```

Is there a formula to do that or do I need VBA? It would be great if I could use a formula for that issue.

thank you very much!

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with a regular worksheet formula, but if you include the VBA function from here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx

Then you can use this formula:

```
=StringConcat(",", IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,$B$2:$B$10,""))
```

Where "partnumber" is in A2:A10, "model series" is in B2:B10, and the formula is entered in C2 (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter since it's an array formula) and filled down.